# Arduino & Python MD5

Tags: python, arduino, md5

Well I tried hashing a string or at least a set of numbers in Python and compare it with the one generated using the MD5 Library updated by Scott MacVicar on the Arduino but the results I get are differents.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <MD5.h> 

void setup()
{
   //initialize serial
   Serial.begin(9600);
   //give it a second
   delay(1000);
   //generate the MD5 hash for our string
   unsigned char* hash=MD5::make_hash("hello");
   //generate the digest (hex encoding) of our hash
   char *md5str = MD5::make_digest(hash, 16);
   //print it on our serial monitor
   Serial.println(md5str);
}
```

Result: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9e4080020008c00

Python Code:

```
from hashlib import md5

m = md5('hello').hexdigest()
print m
```

Result: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

From what I can see in every attempt is that the difference comes at the last 14 characters. But the length of the generated hashes are the same!

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks

Edit:

I used a command from the terminal and got:

```
echo -n 'hello' | openssl md5
```

Result: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

Which makes me think that the root of the problem is in the arduino code

Comment: Did you mean to `echo 'hello'`? I agree though, it's the Arduino that is wrong.

Comment: sorry edited lol yes but I wanted to know what's wrong with the code anyway

Comment: Did you ever resolve this or report this bug to the developer?

Comment: No, I gave up on the idea. I had other problems with other libraries as well but discussions are open for a solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are using the MD5 library from here: https://github.com/tzikis/ArduinoMD5/

It looks like that library has a bug.  The `MD5::make_hash()` function returns a pointer to memory on the stack.  Some of that memory must be being altered before the call to `make_digest()` so the resulting digest is partially wrong.

Comment: Yeah I supposed that there was a bug on the library. Could it be that it's adding a "0" at the end?? I saw that problem a lot of times in forums